# Android Studio not saving github access tokens

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, github, access-token

I am using android studio 3.5.3 on Ubuntu Budgie 19.10, whenever I log into github  from the android studio, it works but only for the current session, when I close and reopen android studio, it says `Missing access token` and asks for login. 
Earlier I was using elementary OS Juno and everything was fine, I did not need to login again and again.

Comment: Most likely a file-system permission issue, because it would have to save it somewhere.

Comment: Seems like but no idea where to find the target file system

Comment: Usually this should be kept somewhere in `~` on Linux, as it is per user.

Comment: I might end up messing entire permission structure :p

Comment: Take ownership with `chown -R $USER:$USER ~/AndroidStudio` (which should already be the case)... there still might be other reasons for it not saving the file.

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: Tried but no luck so far

Comment: Check the SSH keys on Github (which might still be the ones from the other installation). When `git` works on the CLI, it should work in general (even without access token).

Comment: There is no SSH key in my account

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As said by fartem,
you need to set "Save Passwords" option

from "Do not save, forget passwords after restart"

to "Native keychain" or "KeePass"

in File> Settings> Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Passwords

[image: settings]

Answer (score 2):

Faced with the same problem but on Arch. In my case the problem solved after I installed KeePass and configured it by [official docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reference-ide-settings-password-safe.html).